# Animated Nav Menu

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a paint can to tip forward and spill paint. I have 7 images in total, that need animate through. When I do it via css.

It multiples the 1st image then makes it larger so the animation is basically lost. why is css is doing this...a fiddle is attached.

Thanks...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htmL>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="groupx.css">
 <!--  <script src="menuMotion.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider"></div>

</body>
</htmL>
```

and now the CSS

```
body{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
.slider{

        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        background: url(images/blpc1v4.png);
        animation: slide 5s ;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
}
@keyframes slide{

    20%{
        background: url(images/blpc2v3.png);
    }
    38%{
        background: url(images/blpc2v3.png);
    } 
    53%{
        background: url(images/blpc4v3.png);
    } 
    71%{
        background: url(images/blpc5v3.png);
    } 
    90%{
        background: url(images/blpc6v3.png);
    }
    100%{
        background: url(images/blpc7v3.png);
    }
}
```

I'm not actually using the JS code, I'm just including it, the paint can is a menu option -> why there's an eventlistener attached to it.

```
document.images[i].addEventListener('click', animateDropmenu, false);

var frame = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3000;

images [0] = 'images/blpc1v3.png';
images [1] = 'images/blpc2v3.png';
images [2] = 'images/blpc3v3.png';
images [3] = 'images/blpc4v3.png';
images [4] = 'images/blpc5v3.png';
images [5] = 'images/blpc6v3.png';
images [6] = 'images/blpc7v3.png';

function animateDropmenu(){

    document.slide.src = images[0];
    if (frame < images.length - 1){
        frame++;
    }
    else{
        frame = 0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e2571er0/

Comment: Adding actual urls to the JSFiddle would be very helpful here because they come up as 404s and basically make the JSFiddle useless...

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover !important;
```

to your .slider class in CSS.